# How to add OR condition in Swift generic where clause?

Tags: swift, generics, where-clause

I am extending [SCNVector3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnvector3) from Apple SceneKit with arithmetic operations with a number.  I use generic for the number's type, but I have found out that I have to write at least two versions of each function, as this does not work:

```
extension SCNVector3 {
    static func *<T> (left: SCNVector3, right: T) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(left.x * Float(right), left.y * Float(right), left.z * Float(right))
}
```

and gives error **Cannot invoke initializer for Type 'Float' with an argument list of type '(T)'**

Looking at [definition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float) of Float in Apple documentation, I see that the most generic I can get is `init<Source: BinaryFloatingPoint>` or `init<Source: BinaryInteger>`.

So I have to rewrite the extension as following, making two almost identical functions for each operation:

```
extension SCNVector3 {
    static func *<T> (left: SCNVector3, right: T) -> SCNVector3 where T: BinaryFloatingPoint {
        return SCNVector3(left.x * Float(right), left.y * Float(right), left.z * Float(right))

    static func *<T> (left: SCNVector3, right: T) -> SCNVector3 where T: BinaryInteger {
        return SCNVector3(left.x * Float(right), left.y * Float(right), left.z * Float(right))
}
```

I can place AND in `where` clause — by having two conditions after `where` separated by a comma.

But is there any way I can place OR there?

Comment: Technically, you should have only one function taking a `Float`, letting the caller of the function to cast correctly. It kind of does not make sense to enable calling a function with `Double` or `UInt` just to cast the value to a `Float`, possibly truncating precision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your basic implementation should start by this:

```
extension SCNVector3 {
    static func * (vector: SCNVector3, scale: Float) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(vector.x * scale, vector.y * scale, vector.z * scale)
    }
}
```

The vector has `Float` components therefore you should always multiplicate only by a `Float`. That's how all operators in Swift work. If you have a different type, cast it before multiplicating, not as a side-effect of multiplication.

If you *really* want to pass other types, then you can use method overloading:

```
extension SCNVector3 {
    static func *<T> (left: SCNVector3, right: T) -> SCNVector3 where T: BinaryFloatingPoint {
        return left * Float(right)
    }

    static func *<T> (left: SCNVector3, right: T) -> SCNVector3 where T: BinaryInteger {
        return left * Float(right)
    }
}
```

There is no way how to define *or* in types.

Comment: Actually I found the way — use `T: NSNumber` — but decided to stick to the idea that the caller should cast its parameters to `Float`.

Comment: Note: `SCNVector3` has `Float` components on iOS, but `Double` components on macOS _(technically, `CGFloat` components, which a type alias of `Double` on macOS on 64-bit CPUs)_.